# Replace "Chapter 1" to "CHAPTER ONE" in the TOC in report document class

Tags: table-of-contents

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\Numberstring{chapter}}

 \titlecontents{chapter}
    [5.5em] %5.3
    {\bigskip}
    {\contentslabel[\bfseries\textsc{\chaptername}~\thecontentslabel]{5.5em}\textbf}
    {\hspace*{-5.5em}\textbf}
    {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}[\bigskip]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try `\MakeUppercase{}`? For `\Numberstring` to work, you need to load the package `fmtcount`.

Comment: Please  I have done it and does is adding the One and the Two to the sections in the toc which I don't like. Simply like  CHAPTER ONE learning..............6 and for sections 1 discovery.........6  is what I am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that this is what you want, but if you only want to have written out chapter numbers and keep the normal numbers for the sections, you should probably not change the appearance of the chapter number globally.

To convert an integer into a written out number in capitals, you can use `\NUMBERstringnum` from the `fmtcount` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\titlecontents{chapter}
    [10.5em] %5.3
    {\bigskip}
    {\contentslabel[\bfseries\textsc{CHAPTER~\NUMBERstringnum{\thecontentslabel}}]{10.5em}\textbf}
    {\hspace*{-10.5em}\textbf}
    {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}[\bigskip]
    
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Hello}
\section{Bye}

\end{document}
```

[image]